# How to join arguments with a separator?

Tags: arrays, bash

In bash, how to join arguments of a function into a single string?

The seperator is fixed, and is not space (thus `"$*"` is not what I want). Here use `", "` as example.

```
join_args() {
# join args with sep ", ", then echo the joined string
# ... code here
}

join_args abc def ghi
# abc, def, ghi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$*` can work with characters other than space if you set $IFS, but it can only use one character. Thus

```
join_args() {
    local IFS=', '
    echo "${*}"
}
```

outputs `abc,def,ghi`.

If you need longer separators, you have to use a loop:

```
join_args() {
    while (($# > 1)) ; do
        printf '%s, ' "$1"
        shift
    done
    if (($#)) ; then
        printf '%s\n' "$1"
    fi
}
```

Or, use a real programming language:

```
perl -E 'say join ", ", @ARGV' abc def ghi
```

Comment: Your second `join_args()` will loose arg if the args count > 3

Comment: @KonstantinVustin: Oops, thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$ function join_by { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }
```

Then use by:

```
$ join_by , abc def ghi
abc,def,ghi
```

If you want the extra space after the `", "`, use `sed` I suppose:

```
$ join_by , abc def ghi | sed -e 's/,/, /g'
abc, def, ghi
```

Or you can use `printf` with parameter expansion thus:

```
$ function join_by { local d=$1; shift; echo -n "$1"; shift; printf "%s" "${@/#/$d}"; }
$ arr=( abc def ghi "kl mn op" )
$ echo $(join_by ", " "${arr[@]}")
abc, def, ghi, kl mn op
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

join_args() {
  count=$#
  for i in `seq 1 $count`
  do
   if [[ $i = $count ]]
   then
     joined+=("$1")
   else
    joined+=("$1,")
    shift
   fi
  done
echo ${joined[*]}
}

join_args abc def ghi sfl ugw pwg afm
```

Output:

```
abc, def, ghi, sfl, ugw, pwg, afm
```